# Android. Wrong order in imageView assigning

Tags: android, imageview

One view in application has to show some pictures in a row. But they are shown in the wrong order. In this method I get images' names. After I had renamed the images nothing has changed. Any ideas, please?

```
void childParseAttributes(final Properties attributes) {
// ...
        String image = attributes.getProperty("icon");
        if (image.indexOf("png") != -1)
            image = image.substring(0, image.length() - 4);
        int i = Utils.getImageId(image);
        if (i > 0) {
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.footer_icon);
            icon.setBackgroundResource(i);
// ...
}
```

Logcat

```
07-17 14:18:35.553: D/some_app.image(504): card_lock id=2130837532

07-17 14:18:35.562: D/some_app.image(504): card_unlock id=2130837537
```

I've renamed "card_lock" as "card_unlock" and vice versa. New card_lock's id was 2130837532 and new card_unlock's id was 2130837537, i.e. nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you clean + build before running application after changing ids of images?

Comment: First of all, did you checked  you supply correct atributes? if you wull put log.d("image",image); just after String image = attributes.getProperty("icon"); what will it show?

Comment: To Rapunzel. Yes, I did. It happened to be that eclipse with 'build automatically' checkbox on automatically restored previous resources' ids. After I closed eclipse and deleted R.java, application began to work correctly. Thanks for your comment, it brought me a right thought.